# Capybara with Cucumber scenario needed Ruby Rails Application Codio Web_steps

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, cucumber, capybara

The inspect element:

[image]

Here is the web_steps code:

[image]

I need help with a Cucumber scenario that I can make using capybara and my `ruby rails` application to select this dropdown menu in the picture given its HTML and example `web_steps`

Comment: please do not post code as images, use plain text for this

Comment: can you help me with this issue Mr. zhisme I am a student?

Comment: Please show what you’ve tried and what error you’re getting.

Comment: this is the error   And do it                                                                               # features/support/active_proposal.feature:13
      Undefined step: "do it" (Cucumber::Core::Test::Result::Undefined)
      features/support/active_proposal.feature:13:in `do it'                                                                            and I deleted the webstep but it used select(xpath but I was not doing it rightany ways I just need help selecting that option you see in the picture selecting the dropdown menu) it only holds one item that i need to select and